# CakePHP - How to use calculations from associated data in query

Tags: cakephp

I'm trying to figure out the best way to do something - basically I'm looking for advice before I do it the long/hard way!

I have the following model associations:

```
Seller hasMany Invoices
       Invoice hasOne Supplier
               Supplier belongsTo SupplierType
```

Each invoice is for a certain amount and is from a certain date. I want to be able to retrieve Sellers who have spent within a certain amount in the past 'full' month for which we have data. So, I need to get the date 1 month before the most recent invoice, find the total on all invoices for that Seller since that date, and then retrieve only those where the total lies between, say, £10000 and £27000 (or whatever range the user has set).

Secondly, I want to be able to do the same thing, but with the SupplierType included.  So, the user may say that they want Sellers who have spent between £1000 & £5000 from Equipment Suppliers, and between £1000 & £7000 from Meat Suppliers.

My plan here is to do an inital search for the appropriate supplier type id, and then I can filter the invoices based on whether each one is from a supplier of an appropriate type.

I'm mainly not sure whether there is a way to work out the monthly total and then filter on it in one step.  Or am I going to have to do it in several steps?  I looked at Virtual Fields, but I don't think they do what I need - they seem to be mainly used to combine fields from the same record - is that correct?

Comment: What kinds of database are you using. This will require some subqueries, but it is something that can be done in a single query - I am giving a temporary answer below, which may change once I know the database.

Comment: I think he wants to know how to do this through Cake's ORM

Comment: Instead of adding an answer in the question - you should _add an answer_. There's using SO as designed, and potentially more votes for you too then.

Comment: I echo @AD7six's advice here, Sharon. If you discover a solution yourself, please post it in the answer box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*(Posted on behalf of the question author)*.

I'm posting the eventual solution here in case it helps anyone else:

```
SELECT seller_id FROM 
     (SELECT i.seller_id, SUM(price_paid) AS totalamount FROM invoices i 
     JOIN
     (SELECT seller_id, MAX(invoice_date) AS maxdate FROM invoices) sm
     ON i.seller_id = sm.seller_id
     WHERE i.invoice_date > (sm.maxdate - 30) GROUP BY seller_id) t
WHERE t.totalamount BETWEEN 0 AND 1000
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be done in a single query that will look something like:

```
select * from (
select seller, sum(amount) as totalamount
from invoices i join
(select seller, max(invoicedate) as maxdate from invoices group by seller) sm
on i.seller=sm.seller
and i.invoicedate>(sm.maxdate-30)
group by seller
) t where t.totalamount between 1000 and 50000
```

Comment: Wow, thanks, that's really helpful! I'll try it out! I have a few other conditions that need to go in for the seller, so I'll need to figure those out and then give it a go.

Comment: Thank you - got this working, and think I've been able to adapt it for the second scenario as well.  And now I've learned a bit more about how MySQL works, which is great. Don't have room here to post the final solution, but I'll see whether I can add it to the question, in case it helps anyone else. Thanks again!