# Setting up a virtual field with conditions in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp

I have the following models:

```
Retailer hasMany Invoice
```

Each invoice has a date and a retailer_id, as well as price_paid and vat_paid.

I'm paginating the list of Retailers, and I want to get the list of Retailers based on various conditions, including the total amount they have spent in the month preceding the most recent invoice. I asked about performing the [actual search here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23367413/cakephp-how-to-use-calculations-from-associated-data-in-query) and got it working.

Now I need to actually retrieve the total amount along with each Retailer, and I'm not sure how to do that.  I think I need to add it to the fields list, but I can't find a way that you can add SQL queries there. So I'm thinking maybe I need a virtual field? And I'm not sure how those work.

Am I right in thinking that a virtual field will work?  If so, how do I set up a query for that?

Comment: Virtual fields are a convenience, you need to be able to get the right data without using a virtual field first. You are describing what is ordinarily a normal/simple group by query. you need to know the sql to do what you want _first_.

Comment: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/virtual-fields.html  Depending on what you want to do, you may find that dynamically calculating the total becomes too unwieldy.  It's not necessarily bad practice to calculate the total and save it on one of your tables to make later queries simpler.

Comment: Ok, thanks... saving the total as I go along isn't really an option, for various reasons, so I was wanting to just get it on the fly.